# Strange Google Analytics result when new site launched

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, analytics

I have a web site which is mainly contains a few pages, and now we revamp-ed a new site which contains several hundred pages.

We have Strange Google Analytics result, as follow:

```
Before:
Traffic sources (all traffic): 674
Content (all pages, unique PV): 674

After: 
Traffic sources (all traffic): 291
Content (all pages, unique PV): 1235
```

As you can see, the unique PV has increased as expected (as we have more pages now and the site is better), but why the traffic sources is lower and has a large gap?

Any idea?

Comment: Did you put redirects on your previous urls?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal if you are changing sites you will have problems in Google and also your rank can go down to 0.

Can be lot of reasons this are just some general tips.

Check that you don't have any 404 links you can check from Google analitycs for any 404 link. You can also try the httpfox addon in firefox to see if all responses to the site are 200 and there are no problems with any link

create the new site map and import the new site map to google

check your robots.txt and be sure you are allowing all the directories and files you want

see in googles webmasters tools that you don't have link duplication's

do your own counter from the server or your site to see the real traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the folowing analytics reports from before and after the change:

- traffic sources
- landing pages (if your urls have changed try comparing page titles)
- SEO report
- content drilldown (compare visits, not pageviews)

See if you can isolate the differences to particular sources of traffic or parts of your website.